# Swing JMenu problem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jtoolbar

Why I can't add JMenuBar to JToolBar, is it possible? Or I can only add menubar on frame?Tutorial says:

> As the code shows, to set the menu bar for a JFrame, you use the setJMenuBar method. To add a JMenu to a JMenuBar, you use the add(JMenu) method. To add menu items and submenus to a JMenu, you use the add(JMenuItem) method.

And how to set the menu bar for a JToolBar?

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: nothing.like I've never added it.

Comment: why not? without trying you'll not see ;-) And Swing is all about the "G" in GUI

Comment: I mean I try and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you would add a **JMenu** not a **JMenuBar** to a **JToolBar**.  A **JMenuBar** goes accross the frame.

Comment: What isn't working?  You need to post an SSCCE or give a lot more specific detail before anyone can help.